# Forzar el cambio de color de un style definido

Tags: html, css

Me gustaría con una hoja de estilos cambiar el fondo de esta tabla, dado que no puedo cambiar directamente desde el

```
<td style="width: 193px;background-color:#333399; color: #ffffff;">

<p class="negrita2" style="color: #ffffff">Fecha Inscripción</p>

</td>
```

Deseo forzar el cambio de style="width: 193px;background-color:#333399; color: #ffffff;"

Comment: Para modificar la tabla o el `td` por completo en css, elimina todo los estilos (``style`) en el html y trabaja solamente en CSS

Comment: No puedo hacer cambios en el html, quiero hacerle con un style.css

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar `!important`

```css
td{
 background-color:red !important
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width: 193px;background-color:#333399; color: #ffffff;">

<p class="negrita2" style="color: #ffffff">Fecha Inscripción</p>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Las reglas CSS tiene prioridad, algunos le llaman "Especificidad", cuyo orden es más o menos el siguiente

- Estilo en línea, es decir ocupando el atributo style de un elemento
- #ID
- .Clases, [atributos] :pseudoclases
- Elementos y pseudoelementos (input, div, :before, :after)

Es decir un estilo en línea pisa a un estilo #id{}, y este pisa a uno por .clase{} y así sucesivamente

Además, a igual "Especificidad" gana la última regla ingresada.

Entonces el estilo en línea es lo más prioritario, siendo la única alternativa usar `!important`, esto pisa toda la Especificidad; y a varios `!important` también gana el último

Recomiendo leer:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

##### Explicación:

Al agregar una propiedad con la declaración **`!important`**, defines que la regla que ocupa dicha propiedad se interpondrá encima de las demás reglas, es decir, si una clase tiene una propiedad `background-color` y en tu hoja de estilos vuelves a darle la propiedad `background-color` pero con distinto color y la declaración **`!important`**, el estilo que afectará a la clase será el que tenga **`!important`** ya que éste se interpondrá encima de las demás propiedades.

##### Ejemplo:

```css
td{
 background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 193px; background-color:#333399; color: #ffffff;">
      <p class="negrita2" style="color: #ffffff">Fecha Inscripción</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

##### Enlaces:

- [**Declaración !important**](https://uxdivi.com/blog/important-que-es-y-cuando-usarlo)